# FlexSlider2 - Can´t make Full Width, Left and Right White Spaces

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, flexslider

I am trying to make a flexslider 2 Gallery Full Width, but without any sucess.
The FlexSlide is width:100% and I erase the borders. Cant get rid of the white spaces.

http://www.dayoneconcept.pt/emteste/index2.html

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapp your page in div#wrapper and give it thius property

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rewrite the whole code. Its very messy.

There's a element with a 500% negative padding and i see no reason for that, and a bunch of others crazy things.

You will have many problems with this layout if you leave the way it is.